# launch app for intent and return after

Tags: android, android-intent, sdk, android-pendingintent

I know it is possible run an external app from an intent but anyone knows if it is possible return to our app programmatically after this "external app" complete the job we want?

Comment: dont finish you app with finish() after intent and when user make back press with external app he will land in your app. You can not do anything programitically. startActivityForResult may not be included

Comment: if u launch for result and the activity implements the return... it works

Comment: use startActivityForResult, but this also depends on the startet app. Not at all apps it is possible to return, at some apps only if they get stopped.